# Default post statuses not showing in Wordpress administration page

Tags: wordpress

There are [8 default post statuses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status#Default_Statuses) in Wordpress. In the administration page I can only select between: "Published", "Pending Review" and "Draft". Why is that?

I looked through the code and it seems that some JavaScript removes options at runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple scenario, you can't set a post to the trash status, you delete the post and then it is assigned a status of trashed.  Some statuses are internal statuses used by WordPress which are not assignable by users via the drop down in the post administration area.

Comment: All right, I didn't think of that :P
It would be nice to set status to "private", but I guess custom post status is the way to go. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @tomas.js to be honest I've never made the connection either but when you pointed it out I realised why :)  Please accept my answer if you're happy with it.

Comment: Accepted, just what I needed :)